# Which Twitter wrapper libs support Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I'd like to add support for Twitter in a project built with Python 3.2, but I can't figure out which libraries support it.

I've done a bit of googling and I cannot come up with a clear answer; the closest thing I've found is [Twython](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython), mentioning in their readme that it's uber-experimental and you need a hacked version of python-oauth2, so it's basically hacks all the way down; surely there is something better out there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you didn't already know them, you may want to take a look at the [Python Twitter Tools](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/twitter/) that turned out from my bit of googling: they are listed among [Python 3 packages on PyPI](http://pypi.python.org/pypi?%3aaction=browse&c=533&show=all) (under the package name `twitter`), and seem to be [actively developed on GitHub](https://github.com/sixohsix/twitter).

Comment: Yeah, I'll probably end up using this. It's still slightly disconcerting that nobody else bothered with it yet.

Comment: It's a good chance to lead the masses! But, what is it that everyone else is using in Python 2.x land, then?

Comment: Lots of choices over there, mostly based on python-oauth2.

Answer (score 5):

[*Twython*](https://github.com/ryanmcgrath/twython) library now (as time of answering th question) fully support **Python** 3.x, not to mention that it's easy to use and implement, let alone their extensive [***documentation***](https://twython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
As their official documentation says:

> Seamless Python 3 support!
>
> OAuth 2 Application Only (read-only) Support
>
> Support for Twitter’s Streaming API

I've been using it for some time and it's working great for me, so consider giving it another chance.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/geduldig/TwitterAPI

This one supports Python 3.x.

Features include:

- REST and Streaming API
- Premium Search API
- OAuth1 and OAuth2
- Firewall proxy authentication